# How to replace SQLite with Berkeley DB

Tags: berkeley-db

Currently I have developed a c# project with Sqlite3. I need to replace Sqlite3 with Berkeley DB. 
I need to know the followings,
Is it possible to replace? if yes, what should we follow?

Please advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you make this work? and if so how? I would like to know because i need help with this please

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/a/ocom/docs/bdb-sqlite-comparison-wp-176431.pdf provides some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way and a hard way to replace sqlite3 with BerkeleyDB.

The easy way is to replace the sqlite3 libraries with the sqlite3 wrapper library (part of modern Berkeley DB) that uses BerkeleyDB as the data store engine under a modified sqlite3 (it's exactly a sqlite3 API).

The harder implementation would be to rewrite the SQL methods to use Berkeley DB. Since Berkeley DB is basically a NoSQL! key->value store, you will likely need to think about whether your schema is simple enough to justify the work involved.

Comment: But how can you do this? I read the official documentation and they don't explain how to do this or the steps when you installed SQLite with package nuget into your project and later want to do this change, the "directions" from the official website are not clear at all